# Formatters.register compile errors after upgrading from 2.4

Tags: formatter, playframework-2.5

I'm getting those strange 'non static' errors after upgrading from 2.4 to 2.5 when I run 'activator compile':

```
non-static method  <T>register(java.lang.Class<T>,play.data.format.Formatters.SimpleFormatter<T>) cannot be referenced from a static context

public MyController() {
    Formatters.register(Xpto.class, new XptoConverter());
}
```

XptoConverter:

```
public class XptoConverter extends SimpleFormatter<Xpto> {
  @Override
  public Xpto parse(String input, Locale l) throws ParseException {
    return new Xpto().setId(Long.valueOf(input));
  }

  @Override
  public String print(Xpto xpto, Locale l) {
    return xpto.getId().toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are not static any more; the Formatter is injected. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Register-a-custom-DataBinder. See also https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5734

You have to

1. Create a `public class FormattersProvider implements Provider<Formatters>` (which does the conversion)
2. Create a `public class FormattersModule extends AbstractModule`
3. Enable the `FormattersModule` in `application.conf`